# is zef supposed to update the repository when the version of the module changed in a git?

Tags: raku

WHen you have a module in Raku... there is a json file in which the version number is specified of the module.. Is zef supposed to update the repository by checking the given git repository regularly or not? Is zef buggy or it has ever worked?

Comment: Hi @Aftershock. Has the linked SO ("Any way to easily ensure zef is pulling latest versions of raku modules?") explained what you need to know? Please know that `zef` does its job well. Unfortunately there are some social issues (covered in the linked SO, and links from that SO to posts elsewhere such as the reddit one I linked) that may take some time to resolve. But in the meantime you can bypass those problems as explained in the linked SO etc. If what you doesn't clarify things for you, please leave comments on those other pages.

Comment: not so well, it puts the distribution into the distribution... it does not handle username that contains accented characters It does not upload the distribution , only second time... no so well...

Comment: Hi @Aftershock. Thanks for replying. :) "it puts the distribution into the distribution" What do you mean? Have you discussed what you mean somewhere where other Rakoons get what you mean and discuss it so you agree with them about some things? "It does not upload the distribution, only second time..." Same question.

Comment: I think you're confused - `zef` doesn't use usernames for anything, nor does it upload anything

Comment: I meant username under Windows...  e.g C:\Users\Báron\AppData\